# Unable to reference private static member variable: Compiler error

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to use a static member variable as a "dictionary" in a translation program.

I have two files, alphabet.h, which looks like this:

```
#ifndef ALPHABET_H
#define ALPHABET_H
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Alphabet {
  public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> letterType;
    typedef std::map<std::string, letterType> alphabetType;
    alphabetType getAlphabet();
  private:
    static alphabetType m_alphabet;
};

#endif
```

And alphabet.cpp, which looks like this:

```
#include "alphabet.h"

static Alphabet::alphabetType m_alphabet = {{"ὁ",{"o"}}};

Alphabet::alphabetType Alphabet::getAlphabet() {
    return Alphabet::m_alphabet;
}
```

For some reason when I attempt to compile, I get an error from g++.

*In function `Alphabet::getAlphabet[abi:cxx11]()':
alphabet.cpp:6: undefined reference to`Alphabet::m_alphabet[abi:cxx11]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

I would appreciate any insight into what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it's a private variable. your `m_alphabet = {{...}}` is OUTSIDE the class, theefore it's not allowed to do anything with that private variable.

Comment: @MarcB You have to instantiate the variable outside the class.

Comment: BTW, it is a linker error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static Alphabet::alphabetType m_alphabet = {{"ὁ",{"o"}}};
```

should be

```
Alphabet::alphabetType Alphabet::m_alphabet = {{"ὁ",{"o"}}};
```

Here, you define an other variable.

Comment: should be noteworthy, that `static` makes access module local.